# WPF First element of ItemsControl as Expander Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a CustomControl : ItemsControl which should by default only show the first entry (ItemTemplate contains `<Grid><TextBlock/><TextBlock/></Grid>`).

When using an Expander (and it's not expanded) I can only display the Header. When expanded then all of the Items are displayed. 
But actually I want to display the first item as the Expander Header and when expanded it should display all the other items of the itemsource underneath the header.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you considered using a ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want an expandable row
In one of my application I have something like below:
[image]

First line has some details, and by clicking on the expander a list is filled in.
To build up this view I've used a DataGrid which has the RowHeaderTemplate set to an expander:

```
  <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="AddressExpander" telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="True" Expanded="Address_Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Address_Expander_Collapsed">
                            </telerik:RadExpander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
  private void Address_Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            var expander = s as RadExpander;
            if (expander != null)
            {
                var parentRow = s.ParentOfType<DataGridRow>();
                if (parentRow != null)
                {
                    parentRow.IsSelected = true;
                    parentRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }

        }

        private void Address_Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            var expander = s as RadExpander;
            if (expander != null)
            {
                var parentRow = s.ParentOfType<DataGridRow>();
                if (parentRow != null)
                {
                    parentRow.IsSelected = false;
                    parentRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }

        }
```

And for RowDetailsTemplate I have a template which is another DataGrid, in very few tags something like this:

```
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
 <DataGrid  Itemsource = {Binding *property of parent viewmodel here*} />
   </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

The result is in the picture -> an expandable row, which can show in the details a list of other objects. Sure, you can use ListView or ItemsControl or any thing else that fits.
But I think that is a model that you should take a look.